# Multicombobox not visible on clicking back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, combobox

I am trying to develop an online booking system which has different options for each course. When a course is selected a combobox opens where you choose the week that you want the course.
There is an validation function to ensure that certain fields are completed. If you need to go back to complete the form, the combobox is not visible.
Is there any way to make combobox visible?

html as follows
    
    course 1
    course 2 
    course 3 
    Select your course...

The combobox is lifted out of Wordpress as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name= "course1a" value="<?php echo $title;?>,<?php echo     the_field('cost_of_course',$week1a); ?>" />
<select name="date1a" id="date1a"> 
 <option value="">Select Week</option> 
  <?php 

  $categories =get_the_category($week1a); 
  foreach ($categories as $category) {
  if($category->name !== '6 +') 
  if($category->name !== '7+') 
  if($category->name !== '8+') 
  if($category->name !== '9+')
  if($category->name !== '10 +')
  if($category->name !== '11+')
  if($category->name !== 'All')


 $option = '<option value="'.$category->cat_name.'">';
 $option .= $category->cat_name;

 $option .= '</option>';
echo $option;
}
?>
```

The javascript driving this is as follows:

```
function showWeek(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","dates.php?week="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

Any thoughts on how we can make the dropdown show on hitting back button.

booking system can be seen at 
https://www.chiswickcourses.co.uk/wp/online-booking/

Cheers

Ian

Comment: sorry, the main combobox html not visible.
     <select name="course" onchange="showWeek(this.value)">
     <option selected value="1">option 1</option> 
   
     <option selected value="2">option 2</option> 
  
     <option selected value="3">option3</option> 
  <option selected value="">Select your course...</option> 
  </select>

Comment: Not that it's related... but what are you doing with all of those conditionals?

Comment: Why would the client need to push the back button?  It's up to you to make a system that validates through AJAX.  Make sure the client doesn't have to leave the page.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Form validation requires go back to complete form - all done by php
and would Ajax still keep combobox visible. Not building new validation code if it doesnt - it is a very large form

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay they may need to go back to edit the form

Comment: @mevius The conditionals? The weeks are categories in WP and the conditionals exclude the other categories. –

Comment: Your validation is just checking if the fields are empty, right?  All you need is to add the attribute "required" to all input elements that are required.  Then no further validation is needed (well, you should still double check, but this is mostly redundant), and there is no need for the client to use the back button.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay as I said, they may wish to go back and edit course options